# unexpected lack of variable expansion in fish shell

Tags: fish

This is version 2.1.0

```
$ set a foo
$ set b bar
$ echo $a_$b

$ echo {$a}_$b
foo_bar
```

Why does the first "echo" output nothing? I would have expected to see "bar"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to realize is that underscores are valid in an identifier, so the variable that gets expanded is not `$a` but `$a_`.

Now `$a_` is unset, which means it treated like a list of zero entries. Unquoted variable substitution works by expanding the parameter separately for every element in the list, for example:

```
> set a 1 2 3
> echo {$a}_x
1_x 2_x 3_x
```

In the original question, `$a_` is empty. The parameter is expanded separately for every element in the list, which is empty, so the result is nothing at all. This is why it outputs nothing.

Double-quoted expansions work differently: the list entries are joined by spaces, and then expanded.

```
> set a 1 2 3
> echo "$a"_x
1 2 3_x
```

and this may behave more like you expect:

```
> set a foo
> set b bar
> echo "$a"_"$b"
foo_bar
> echo "$a_"$b
bar
```

Comment: Thank you, great explanation. I'm coming from bash where things are  just strings (unless you throw lots of syntax at them). I've got to get used to fish variables are lists unless protected with strings.